# Can't run project when update Android gradle plugin version

Tags: android, gradle

I have updated Android gradle plugin version since 3.5.4 to 3.6.2, when I run my project, got error:

```
Cannot cast object 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2$1@34d850f' with class 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2$1' to class 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask'
```

It did not happen in version 3.5.4.

Here is my project infomation:

Android Studio 3.6.2

Android gradle plugin 3.6.2

Gradle 6.3

buildToolVersion 29

compileSdkVersion 29

Could someone help me? Thanks!

------update------

I have solved the problem, that's becase one plugin in my project was not support the new gradle version, so I update it, then everything is fine.

Here is my solution:

1.Android gradle plugin version is above 3.6.0 (mine is 3.6.2);

2.Your gradle version is above 6.0 (mine is 6.3) in gradle-wrapper.properties;

3.check all plugin in your project, are they all support the new gradle version.

Hope can help.

Comment: Try invalidate caches/restart

Comment: I try, but it's not work.

Comment: Set it to 3.6.1

Comment: Do a clean build. What build plugins did you apply apart from android and kotlin?

Comment: I solved the problem. It's happens by another plugin which include in my project, so I update it too, everything is fine!  Thanks for @EugenPechanec suggestion.

Comment: @Ryan Glad I could help. Now you can either expand your question with necessary details and provide your own answer, to help others, or you can delete the question altogether. Thanks for keeping SO clean.